# Why does not null in LINQ query still return null records?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Why does the LINQ query return records that are null? I'm using the code below to no avail.

```
var list = (from t in dal.table
            where t.name != null);
```

Comment: What's the data type of name?

Answer (score 27):

You forgot to `select`.

```
var list = (from t in dal.table
            where t.name != null
            select t);
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot about that.  But when I do have the select I still don't get the records that have a value in the name field.

Comment: @MdeVera: Do you need `string.IsNullOrEmpty`? (Not sure, just a guess.)

Comment: @MdeVera: Make sure they're really null. The missing `select` is all I can think of right now

Comment: @MdeVera you could also add a `.toList()` to force Linq to evaluate the query immediately, perhaps your running into an issue trying to evaluate the query after your connection has already been closed.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same strange behavior. The C# code is

```
public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
List<Document> = Documents
    .Where(d => d.BusinessId = 818)
    .Where(d => d.CurrencyId != null)
    .ToList();
```

but the SQL statement generated is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[DocumentId] AS [DocumentId], 
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated],
...
FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[BusinessId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=818
```

Clearly LINQ ignores the .Where(d => d.CurrencyId != null) clause.

My solution was as follows:

```
List<Document> = Documents
    .Where(d => d.BusinessId = 818)
    .ToList() // <== Gel all documents and filter in memory
    .Where(d => d.CurrencyId != null)
    .ToList();
```

*Note: Technically we move the NOT Null filter from Linq-To-Sql to Linq-To-objects.*

Very inefficient since we select ALL the documents into memory and filter there (instead of filtering in the db-level).

I my case the number of records is usually small so the solution worked for me.

Comment: This would suggest that your model doesn't match the real database -- that the model is for a database where `CurrencyId` is not nullable.